# Change bootstrap's collapse panel background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am using `Bootstrap`s 3 collapse panels that look like [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afkgs.png) when closed.

I wish to change the background and text color to something else, I believe the `css` snippet that is interresting is the following (in `bootstrap.css`):

```
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}
.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
}
.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.panel-heading > .dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  color: inherit;
}
```

And here is how I implement one collapse panel using `Jade`:

```
div(class='panel-group' id='accordion2' role='tablist' aria-multiselectable='true')
        div(class='panel panel-default')
            div(class='panel-heading' role='tab' id='headingOneA2')
                h4(class='panel-title')
                    a(role='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion2'
                    href='#collapseOneA2' aria-expanded='true' aria-controls='collapseOneA2') 42sh
            div(id="collapseOneA2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOneA2")
                div(class='panel-body')
                    p Coded a fully functionnal shell environment in C offering features such as pipes, redirection, dynamic completion etc.
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to change the background / text colors and my research has not been conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loosing a specificity war with Bootstrap's css. Remove the class `panel-default` and then apply your css as attached.

```css
.panel-heading {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.panel-body {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel">
    <div role="tab" id="headingOneA2" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOneA2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOneA2">42sh</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOneA2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOneA2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Coded a fully functionnal shell environment in C offering features such as pipes, redirection, dynamic completion etc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```